# Rails: finding matches that start with a string and do not end in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, match

I've got this little thing here:

```
def get_articles
  @articles = []
  Doc.column_names.each do |a|
    if a.match(/^article/)
      @articles << a
    end
  end
end
```

But it returns a lot of unwanted results. How would I go about discarding results it returns that end in a specific string (say, `_body`)?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if a.match(/^article/) and !a.match(/_body$/)
```

Incidentally, your method can be rewritten ([more compactly](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all)) as:

```
def get_articles
  @articles = Doc.column_names.select { |a| a.match(/^article/) && !a.match(/_body$/) }
end
```

You can also replace the dual match with a single match containing a [zero-width negative look-behind assertion](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html), but it is less readable for the majority of people (though about 2x as fast in a quick-and-dirty test):

```
def get_articles
  @articles = Doc.column_names.select { |a| a.match(/^article.*(?<!_body)$/) }
end
```